# Could not create directory '//.ssh': No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sshd

I'm running SSHD on my Windows machine, which I downloaded from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi

I was able to run SSHD, but whenever I tried to connect from the same machine, it gives the following error.

```
C:\Users\fk>ssh fk1@localhost -p 8000
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
fk1@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
fk1@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
fk1@localhost's password:
Permission denied (password,keyboard-interactive,publickey).
```

I thoght it related to not having publickey, so I tried to create publickey by running ssh-keygen, but it gives the following error.

```
C:\Users\fk>ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):
Could not create directory '//.ssh': No such file or directory
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
open //.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: //.ssh/id_rsa.
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this :

Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):

Enter a valid Windows path , D:\id_rsa  to create private public key pair , and add public key to other hosts known hosts file

Comment: Cannot go to //.ssh/id_rsa, since this directory does not exist.

Comment: Thats why I asked to write a path that exists , like D:\id_rsa after the program asks you to "Enter file in which to save the key"